# How many number of ordered pair $(m, n)$ can be formed if $m+n=190$ and $m$ and $n$ are positive integers and coprime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The question involves the concept of number theory

Kindly provide the hints to solve the question not the entire solution

I don't know how to approach these kind of problems

Comment: If you don't mind can you upload the entire solution

Comment: You start with all $m$, $1\le m\le189$, and throw out all $m$ that are multiples of the prime divisors of $190$. This will involve using the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion.

Comment: Thank you for providing hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $d=\gcd(m,190-m)$, then $d|190=2 \cdot 5 \cdot 19$. But we want $d=1$, so $2,5,19 \not| m$. So we want $m \in S=\{1,2,3, \ldots, 189\}$ such that $m$ is not divisible by $2, 5$ or $19$.

Let $P_i:= \text{property that }m \text{ is divisible by }i$ and $n(P_i):=$ number of integers in $S$ that have property $P_i$

Then we want $$n(\bar{P_2} \cap \bar{P_5} \cap \bar{P_{19}})=N-\left[n(P_2)+n(P_5)+n(P_{19})\right]+\left[n(P_2 \cap P_5)+n(P_2 \cap P_{19})+n(P_5 \cap P_{19})\right]-\left[n(P_2 \cap P_5 \cap P_{19})\right].$$
Thus,
$$n(\bar{P_2} \cap \bar{P_5} \cap \bar{P_{19}})=189-\left[94+37+9\right]+\left[18+4+1\right]-\left[0\right]=\color{red}{72}.$$
So the number of values that $m$ can take is $72$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution

Comment: "Kindly provide the hints to solve the question **not the entire solution**"